# Calculating the degree matrix having the sparse representation of the adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to calculate the laplacian matrix of a graph. I ve calculated the sparse representation of the adjacency matrix which is stored in a text file with dimension Nx3. N the size of nodes (ith-node jth node weight). I open in Matlab this file with `adj = spconvert(adj);`. The next step is to calculate the degree matrix of this sparse matrix  in order to perform the operation `L = D - adj`. How is it possible to calculate the degree matrix having as an input the sparse adjacency matrix of the graph? In order to calculate the degree matrix I calculate the degree for every node:

```
for i=1:n % size of the node
    degree(i) =  length(find(adj(:,1) == i & adj(:,3) == 1));
end
```

However, how can I perform the subtraction of D and A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [spdiags](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) function to convert the degree vector to a sparse diagonal matrix. Then subtract the adjacency matrix from diagonal matrix to get the Laplacian. Example using your code:

```
adj = spconvert(adj);
for i=1:size(adj, 1)
    degree(i) = CalcDegree(adj, i)
end
D = spdiags(degree, 0, size(adj, 1), size(adj, 2));
L = D - adj;
```

By the way, your code for calculating the node degree may be incorrect.

Comment: Degree matrix size is the size of of nodes. however the adj matrix has different size which is the number of edges. With the CalcDegree I guess you mean my method. I am getting problems with spdiags  
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> spdiags at 114
         a((len(k)+1):len(k+1),:) = [i i+d(k) B(i+(m>=n)*d(k),k)];

Comment: Your code for calculating the node degree fits the 3-column representation of the adjacency matrix in the text file, not the representation after parsing the text file with spconvert, which should be a matrix whose number of rows and columns equals the number of vertices, not the number of edges (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). This also should be the reason you are getting incorrect dimensions.

Comment: Yea you are right, but I calculate the sparse representation of the adjacency matrix. Thus, instead of having a NxN matrix I ve just have the active set of  edges.

Comment: No need for that. Matlab stores sparse matrices efficiently in its sparse matrix object type, which you get by using spconvert.

Comment: Ok I like your comment, however degree it has to be calculated using the initial sparse representation?

Comment: You can calculate the degree of the i'th node in the matrix representation by summing the elements (or counting the nonzero elements) in the i'th column.